Exchange GCP access token for id token
I am using vault and the gcp engine to get access tokens for a service account (token based RoleSet). I am trying to use the received token to call a cloud function (with authentication). However after failing, I realise now that I need an id_token in the Authorization header of the request, however the token given to me from vault is an 'access' token.
Is there a way to use an access token for GCP to generate an id_token for use with cloud functions?

@ Shane Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes,could you please have a look at this doc and accordingly proceed.

Yes, there is a solution and it's named Service Account Credential API. You can generate an ID token thanks to it. And because it's a Google Cloud API, you must use an access token to invoke it.
I also write an article on this API

Thanks so much for this. Once you given the SA of the access_token, service-account-token-creater permission on the SA you want an id_token for, it works nicely.

There is no direct way to use an access token for GCP to generate an id_token for use with Cloud Functions.
But you can use an access token for GCP to generate an id_token with Cloud Functions. You can use OAuth 2.0 to exchange a GCP access token for an ID token.
You will get an access token from the Vault which is linked to the Service Account. Access token is used for authorization to access Google APIs. If you are using it in a Python environment, you can use the google auth library.
If you are working in a different environment, you can use any HTTP client to make requests to OAuth tokens. After that you can use the access token to get an ID token.
Once you have an ID token, you can make an HTTP request to your Cloud Function with the Authorization header set to Bearer.
Another way to use the access token to request an ID Token with the IAM Service Account credentials API:
As you said, you will get an access token from the vault which is linked to the GCP service account. Access token is used for authorization to access Google APIs.
With the Access Token you can now make a request to Google IAM API to get an ID token. Use the IAM service Account credentials API to generate an ID token by making an authorized request using the access token.
Also go through  this  Vault Google Cloud auth method, which may helps to resolve your issue.
